# Date Calculated Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to take someone's birthday and find the day that he/she turns 65. I have the following code but the calculation seems off. For example, if I use the birthday 11/15/1957 I should get 11/15/2022 as the 65th birthday. However, I'm getting 8/9/1982 (which is incorrect) instead.

Am I missing something?

```js
function convertDate(birthday) {

  var usethisdate = new Date(birthday);

  //let's start by finding the person's 65th birthday

  var birthdaysixtyfive = new Date(usethisdate.setMonth(usethisdate.getMonth() + 780));
  console.log("65th birthday: ", birthdaysixtyfive.toDateString());
}

convertDate('11/15/1957');
```

Comment: Do you want to get the day like sunday, monday etc..??

Comment: This is working fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/uxw07mbf/

Comment: Exactly what value are you using for `birthday`? The `Date` constructor is picky about what you pass to it

Comment: Converting your code to a runnable snippet shows it returns the expected result. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: I'm using   I'm creating a date object, assigning the following date and trying to pass it through the function. 
``` 
const givenDate = new Date(11,15,1957);
convertDate(givenDate);
```
I'm wanting to get a result "65th birthday is: 11/15/2022"

Comment: I ran the code snippet on this website and it looks like it worked, I'm not getting the results to translate into google Apps Scripts. Is there something I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Just add 65 to the provided year. And you'll get the result. Below code should do the work.

```js
let birthDay = new Date('11/15/1957')

function getDay(birthDay){
  let birthYear = birthDay.getFullYear() + 65
  let birthArr = birthDay.toDateString().split(' ')
  let calculatedDay = new Date(`${birthYear}-${birthArr[1]}-${birthArr[2]}`).toDateString()
  return calculatedDay
}

console.log(getDay(birthDay))
```

Comment: I get "Invalid Date". See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score -1):

Your code is ok. I think you want like this format :

```js
function convertDate(birthday) {

var usethisdate = new Date(birthday);

//let's start by finding the person's 65th birthday

var birthdaysixtyfive = new Date(usethisdate.setMonth(usethisdate.getMonth()+780));

    birthdaysixtyfive

    bd65 = (birthdaysixtyfive.getMonth() + 1)+'/'+birthdaysixtyfive.getDate()+'/'+birthdaysixtyfive.getFullYear();
    
    console.log("65th birthday: ",bd65);
}


convertDate('11/15/1957');
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the code is ok, why am I still getting the wrong answer?

Comment: By run the above code I am getting on console: 65th birthday:  11/15/2022. Is not that you wanted?

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using the 'momentjs' library. It has a function for difference.

```
const moment = require('moment')
function convertDate(birthday) {

    var usethisdate = new Date(birthday);
    
    //let's start by finding the person's 65th birthday
    
    var age  = moment().diff(usethisdate, 'years');
    console.log("Age: ",age);
    var currentDate = moment();
    var year = moment(currentDate).add(age, 'Y').format('DD-MM-YYYY'); //or replace age with 65
    console.log("Xth birthday: ",year);
    }

    convertDate(11/15/1957)
```

Comment: Moment.js themselves recommend not using that library for new code. See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/